# Not getting rows from database. SQLite, Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I have a function inside DatabaseHelper.kt:

```
fun readData_Inventory(barcode: String): Inventory{ 
        val p0 = this.readableDatabase
        val selection = "$COL_PRODUCTID = ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(barcode)
        val cursor = p0.query(TABLE_INVENTORY, null, selection, selectionArgs,null, null, null)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Barcode: $barcode, Count: ${cursor.count}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val inventory: Inventory?
        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            cursor.moveToLast()
            val productId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PRODUCTID))
            val quantity = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_QUANTITY))
            val source = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_SOURCE))
            val dateCheck = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_DATECHECK))
            inventory = Inventory(productId, quantity, source, dateCheck)
        } else{
            inventory = Inventory ("000", 0.0, "", "")
        }
        return inventory
```

But the `Toast` shows 0 in `cursor.count`.

I know the table has rows because when I run the next code it brings the rows I'm looking for:

```
fun readData_Inventory(barcode: String): Inventory{ 
        val p0 = this.readableDatabase
        val sql = "select * from $TABLE_INVENTORY"
        val cursor = p0.rawQuery(sql, null)
        val inventory: Inventory?
        Toast.makeText(context, "Barcode: $barcode, Count: ${cursor.count}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            cursor.moveToLast()
            val productId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PRODUCTID))
            val quantity = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_QUANTITY))
            val source = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_SOURCE))
            val dateCheck = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_DATECHECK))
            inventory = Inventory(productId, quantity, source, dateCheck)
        } else{
            inventory = Inventory ("000", 0.0, "", "")
        }
        return inventory
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I tried with the next code:

```
fun readData_Inventory(barcode: String) {
        val p0 = this.readableDatabase
        val inventory: Inventory?
        val sql = "select * from $TABLE_INVENTORY"
        val cursor = p0.rawQuery(sql, null)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Size: ${cursor.count} Move: ${cursor.moveToFirst()}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        /////////////////
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val productId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PRODUCTID))
        Toast.makeText(context, "ID: $productId", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

When I run the code with only the first part (before the /////// part), the toast shows `"Size: 1, true"` (that's ok, my table only has 1 row). But when I add the second part (after the ////////) it shows the error: `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

I'm adding the part where I insert the data... maybe is that...

```
fun insertData_Inventory(inventory: Inventory){
        val p0 = this.writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_PRODUCTID, inventory.product_id)
        cv.put(COL_QUANTITY, inventory.quantity)
        cv.put(COL_SOURCE, inventory.source)
        cv.put(COL_DATECHECK, inventory.checkDate)
        val result = p0.insert(TABLE_INVENTORY, null, cv)
        if (result == (-1).toLong())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Insert Inventory Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Insert Inventory Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        p0.close()
    }
```

It always inserts and shows "Insert Inventory Success"

Also the part where I declare the table:

```
val TABLE_INVENTORY = "Inventory"
val COL_INVENTORYID = "inventory_id"
val COL_PRODUCTID = "product_id"
val COL_QUANTITY = "quantity"
val COL_SOURCE = "source"
val COL_DATECHECK = "date_check"
val CREATE_T_INVENTORY = "CREATE TABLE if not exists $TABLE_INVENTORY " +
        "(" +
        "$COL_INVENTORYID integer PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "$COL_PRODUCTID varchar(20), " +
        "$COL_QUANTITY double, " +
        "$COL_SOURCE varchar(20)," +
        "$COL_DATECHECK datetime, " +
        "FOREIGN KEY($COL_PRODUCTID) REFERENCES $TABLE_PRODUCT($COL_PRODUCTID)" +
        ")"
```

Any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use `"""` so that you don't need to do all this `+` stuff.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm sorry I don't know what do you mean

Comment: `"""CREATE TABLE if not exists $TABLE_INVENTORY ( $COL_INVENTORYID integer PRIMARY KEY, ...."""`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce does that work even with multiple lines? Because I'm not so good at this (you can see this question and how I solved it after 2 days of debugging), I need the structure I put in here or else I become crazy. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it works with multiple lines.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that's amazing, I will use it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a line when initializing my object:

inventory.product_id = product.product_id

Thanks, especially [@mTak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8959091/mtak)

Answer (score 1):

Try the whole statement in a `rawquery`:

```
val sql = "select * from $TABLE_INVENTORY WHERE trim($COL_PRODUCTID) = '$barcode'"
val cursor = p0.rawQuery(sql, null)
```

I assume barcode is TEXT

Comment: Thanks! Still not working. with `'$barcode'` and without the apostrophe... `barcode` is `varchar`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Same, doesn't work... (sorry for the late reply, this is part of my thesis project but I had to go to work, thanks for your time, I appreciate it).

Comment: A friend of mine said to try `select * from $table where $COL_PRODUCTID like '%$barcode%` and it doesn't work either...

Comment: If you have time, please check the edit in my original question. Thanks